# How to send spl-tokens with Solana smart contract?

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

I'm a beginner Rust/Solana Developer and wanted to ask if someone knows how to send a spl-token from an account when the account receives a SOL?

I read the https://docs.solana.com/ but i could not find anything about SPL transfers.

Example of Smart Contract: https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld

**Example:**

**Acc1** sends ****0.1** SOL** to a address and for that **Acc1** receives **1 SPL-TOKEN** from that address.

*Simple explanation: I need a minting website for a token.*

I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send SPL-Tokens by using CPI on the token program's transfer instruction.

For example:

```rust
spl_token::instruction::transfer(
  token_program.key,
  source.key,
  destination.key,
  authority.key,
  &[],
  amount,
)?;
invoke_signed(
  &ix,
  &[source, destination, authority, token_program],
  signers,
)
```

You can find a more in depth example by looking at how the token-swap program uses CPI to [transfer spl-tokens](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-swap/program/src/processor.rs#L138-L151)

Comment: lookd good thx!